# SQL Server Management Studio equivalent for CTR+L keyboard Shortcut from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, sql-server-2008, ssms-2005

I have not been able to find the equivalent shortcut key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> used in Visual Studio (to cut and copy a line) in SQL Server 2005/2008. I find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to be very handy.

Does anyone know a keyboard shortcut to cut and copy a line in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> **with no text selected** - this *copies* the current line; likewise <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> **with no text selected** *cuts* the current line.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution.

In 2008 SSMS you can right click the toolbar. Choose customize then in the "Edit" section drag the "Line Cut" item up to the Edit menu.

[image].

Then pressing  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> followed by  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  works.

But I couldn't figure out how to then map that to the single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> combination. This is by default mapped to "Show Estimated Execution Plan" and I didn't find a way to change that.